# Haskell show definition for custom datatype has inconsistent use of leading quotations

Tags: haskell, show

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm working on

```
data ArithExp = Con Int
          | Add ArithExp ArithExp

instance Show ArithExp where
          show (Con i)     = show i
          show (Add e1 e2) = show "( " ++ show e1 ++ " + " ++ show e2 ++ " )"
```

So, if I run the command

```
Add (Con 6) (Con 0)
```

The output I want is:

```
( 6 + 0 )
```

But the code above prints:

```
"( "6 + 0 )
```

As far as I can tell, the show function is printing the quotes in the first string as characters but then using them as correctly in the concatenation that follows. The behavior seems really inconsistent to me. Any insights that will help me get the right output would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the `(Add e1 e2)` branch `show` is binding more tightly than `(++)`, so your code is, more parenthetically,

```
show (Add e1 e2) = (show "( ") ++ (show e1) ++ " + " ++ (show e2) ++ " )"
```

The trick is that you don't really need that leading `show`---you're generating the string directly and only need `show` applied recursively to `e1` and `e2`.

```
show (Add e1 e2) = "( " ++ show e1 ++ " + " ++ show e2 ++ " )"
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, `show` will try to print your data in a way that, if you were to type it into ghci, it would evaluate to an equivalent data value. Think about what that means in the case of a string. How do you type a string value in such that Haskell interprets it as a string rather than an expression to evaluate?

Here's a sample ghci session illustrating what I mean:

```
> let myString = "Hello"
> putStrLn $ show myString
=> "Hello"
> :t "Hello"
=> "Hello" :: String
> putStrLn myString
=> Hello
> :t Hello
=> Not in scope: data constructor 'Hello'
```

Since you had to type your string in quotes originally so that it would evaluate to a string instead of a constructor expression, `show` will put quotes around it so you could paste the value back into ghci and get a string value instead of a constructor value.

While `show`'s behavior may seem a little counter-intuitive in your example, it's actually very consistent in how it behaves. Hopefully knowing why it behaves this way will help you to avoid running into a problem like this in the future!